# How to hook my window to a window of external program?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am writing a C# application where a window in my application is associated to the window of some third party application. Whenever a window of the external program is created, my window should appear right next to that window and disappear when the window is closed.

I am using `AccessibleEvents` and `pinvoke` to create/destroy/reposition my window according to third party window changes. I have a requirement that whenever a third party window is selected (comes to the foreground), my window should be just behind the third party window. Whenever my window is selected, then again the third party window should come to the foreground and my window should be just behind the third party window.

I tried using `SystemForeground` and `SetForegroundWindow` windows to achieve this, but I not able to find a correct way.

What is the correct way to achieve this? Or, is there any way to safely bind the two windows together? I tried using `SetWindowLong` as well, but it looks to risky as ownership of the window will be transferred to the 3 party window.

Below is the code:

```
private void SystemForeground(IntPtr winEventHookHandle, AccessibleEvents accEvent, IntPtr windowHandle, int objectId, int childId, uint eventThreadId, uint eventTimeInMilliseconds)
{
    int nRet;

    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(256);
    //Get the window class name
    nRet = NativeMethods.GetClassName(windowHandle, className, className.Capacity);

    if (nRet != 0)
    {
        if (accEvent == AccessibleEvents.SystemForeground)
        {
            if ((string.Compare(className.ToString(), "3rdPartyWindow", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0))
            {
                // Check if this 3 party window is mapped to our window.
                if (convWindowButtonTable.ContainsKey(windowHandle))
                {
                    Form form =(Form)convWindowButtonTable[windowHandle];
                    NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(form.Handle, windowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, NativeMethods.SWP_NOMOVE | NativeMethods.SWP_NOSIZE);
                }
            }
            // Check if this 3 party window for which event is received is mapped to our window.
            else if (buttonConvWindowTable.ContainsKey(windowHandle))
            {
                IntPtr foreGrnd = NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow();
                IntPtr convWndHndl = (IntPtr)buttonConvWindowTable[windowHandle];
                if (foreGrnd.ToInt32() != convWndHndl.ToInt32())
                {
                    NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(convWndHndl);
                }
            }
        }
    }            
}
```